# performance difference sql query with LINQ and classic asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, asp-classic

I'm developing an asp.net web forms 4.5 website,
and I've come to a problem where I have to perform an sql query
from sql server originally written by classic asp.

The original query goes like this..

```
select trait1, trait2, sum(qty) as qty from table2
right outer join table1 on (table1.col == table2.col)
where table2.idx is null 
group by trait1, trait2
order by trait1, trait2
```

and as I'm writing a .net program, I'm trying to rewrite this query...
as something like this

```
var myHashSet = new HashSet<string>(table2.Select(c => c.col));

from item in table2
where !myHashSet.Contains(item.col)
group item.qty by new {item.trait1, item.trait2} into total
select new
{
    trait1 = total.Key.trait1,
    trait2 = total.Key.trait2,
    qty = total.Sum()
} into anon
order by anon.qty descending
select anon
```

ps : ignore the order by part.. it's not important

for classic asp, it takes like 1.5 seconds, but for c# asp.net,
it takes roughly 8 seconds.

The queries are not exactly like that but its almost similar to what I wrote.

I cannot figure out why it's taking so long..
Can someone tell me why it's taking so long and how I should fix it?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is that you’re loading everything from the second table into the hash set (the `Where` doesn’t limit anything) and then using a client side operation to check every single row from table1 for not matching. That’s going to be a lot more inefficient than letting the database do it like in the original query. Why not just use the original?

Comment: i guess there must be some typos floating around right? 
.Where(c => c.idx == c.idx)?

Comment: I've tried using the same query but resulted in out of memory error so many times so this was the way I succeeded. But maybe I should take your advice and try more with the original one.

Comment: @DanDohotaru You're right. I guess we don't need that.

Comment: Just write your query in LINQ in the similar fashion as SQL, using `from-join`. You simply have very inefficient LINQ (where hashset), hence performance issues. In fact, there are LINQ optimizers out there that might help you.

Comment: what do you expect to have in your hashset anyway? all the col of table1 or table2? as it is now they are based on table2, and in the query where clause you deny its existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need the hashset, use a join instead, your query might look like

```
var inner = from two in table2
            join one in table1
                on two.col equals one.col
            group two by new
            {
                two.trait1,
                two.trait2
            } into total
            select new
            {
                total.Key.trait1,
                total.Key.trait2,
                qty = total.Sum(p => p.qty)
            };
```

**Edit**
for completeness i'm adding also a left join variant

```
var left = from two in table2
            from one in 
            (
                from temp in table1
                where temp.col == two.col
                select temp
            ).DefaultIfEmpty()
            group two by new
            {
                two.trait1,
                two.trait2
            } into total
            select new
            {
                total.Key.trait1,
                total.Key.trait2,
                qty = total.Sum(p => p.qty)
            };
```

Comment: sure thing, but at least from the little details in the original description, the right outer join would not change anything... keep in mind though, that at least for my answer, i base the query on table2 as opposed to table1

Comment: Actually rene is right, I do need an outer join, but actually I tried the join and succeeded and it takes now aobut 1 second to proceed, and I also give you credit for fast response. Thanks!

Comment: great, i've added also the left outer join variant, just for future references sake